# GitHub API Token-use from other IP addresses

Tags: api, github, ip, token, vps

actual I´m working on my master thesis and try to gather data from the Github API with a token to get up my allowed number of requests. This works great on my homecomputer. However, due that the amount of data is very large, I want to use a Linux VPS for this work. I set up everything and ran the same code, however the allowed number of request stays at 60, while from my homecomputer with the same code I get 5000 available requests. Even with a new Token, the number of allowed request doesn´t go up for the server. I always have only 60 on the VPS.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Best regards from Germany!
Tobias

Comment: If it doesn help to answer my question: I believe its about the IP-adress I use. Maybe GitHub doesn´t allow the new IP adress to use the token. However, I created a new token on the Server, but this also does not work

Comment: How are you specifying the token to use?  Can you show the relevant portion of the code you're using for this purpose?

Comment: ###cURL Request part </br>
token = open(r"C:\Users\................\GithubToken.txt", "r") <br>
token = token.read() <br>
authority = ('username', token)

Comment: the second part is:                                       actualURL = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/' <br>
actualURL = actualURL + str(organizations.iloc[i]['org_login']) + '/repos?page=' + str(page) <br>
 r = requests.get(actualURL, auth = authority) <br>
            contentString = r.text

Comment: I also used now directly curl in the terminal, there the direct command worked